# Java - Can Client also acts as a Server at the same time or Vice Versa?

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

Well I am working on a project where I am required to write a TCP/IP Client-Server program. Well on it's own it's quite simple but I have been asked to do something which I have never done before.

I want to know, can I write a Java Client Application which send out commands to a server and gets response from the server. Also, the Server is able to send the same commands to the Client and receive similar responses.

In simple terms, I am asked to write an application in which a Client is at the same time a Server too (not of it's own but for the Server which it connects to) and vice versa.

> For example, if Client requests a Video Feed of Camera 01 to the server, the server sends back an acknowledgement. Right after that, if Server wants, it can send a request to view Video of Camera 02 to the client and the client will reply back accordingly as well.

**Can this be done?!?** If yes, please some advice will be great as I am not sure how to deal with it, maybe Multithreading I guess. If yes, How?!? Some help will be great.

Comment: What have you attempted? Have you ever done any networking in Java before? If not, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html).

Comment: Yes I have. Well actually I was looking for a way so that I could avoid multithreading ... thanks for the link Jeffrey.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop multi threaded application at both the sides. At server two threads will be there one for receiving the packets and another for sending the packets. At the client side same thing you can do.

Comment: Just what I was trying to avoid ... Multithreading but I guess, it's eminent and needs to be done ... well thanks a lot Bhavik, I'll start working on it then

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. In fact, [Peer-to-Peer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) applications do exactly this. Instead of a client or server, you have a peer, which is both a client and a server at the same time. You will certainly have to use multithreading to get this to work.

Comment: Hey, thanks ... well to be honest, I was trying to avoid Multi-threading hahahahaha ... but I guess it's eminent ... Well thanks once again ... I'll start working on it then ...